# UIDate Picker background color

Tags: iphone

HI I would like to change the background color of the UIDatePicker from the current glossy image to clear just like in this example

[image]
<sub>(source: [apple.com](http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/009/Purple/c6/22/0c/mzl.purwdyaq.320x480-75.jpg))</sub>

Any ideas how to do that? I tried

datepicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

but it didnt work.

Answer (score 5):

UIDatePicker contains one subview. That subview, in turn, contains 15 other subviews that form UIDatePicker's appearance. The first and the last of them are the background, so to make it transparent just turn them off and set background color of main subview to clearColor:

```
// create the picker
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 320)];

// add it to some view first
[actionSheet addSubview:datePicker];
[datePicker release];

// clear the background of the main subview
UIView *view = [[datePicker subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

// hide the first and the last subviews
[[[view subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setHidden:YES];
[[[view subviews] lastObject] setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: Is this going to be accepted by Apple?  It seems like it's relying on  internal implementation details that could change in future versions.

Comment: Sure, UIDatePicker internal implementation could be changed in future by Apple. As for app review process, there are several UI elements which don't allow to change their background (like UIDatePicker, UISearchBar etc.), but in some applications they would look awkwardly with default background. Whereas such kind of control tweaking isn't a good practice, Apple know about UI elements limitations and allow applications contain customized controls if they look good.

Comment: I'll have to think about it.  It seems too dangerous to me for my app.  We don't have a maintenance contract from the client, and so we have to hope it lives as long as possible without being broken by platform changes.  Messing around with the internal implementation may be okay, but seems more likely to break in the next version of iOS, so I don't know if we can take the risk.  Thanks for the feedback, in any case.