# Xcode - UIDatePicker background color

Tags: objective-c, ios5

[image]My UIDatePicker's background is black (because the background for the whole screen is black probably), but I want white in the background for this UIDatePicker.

Is there any way to change the background color without subclassing it?

Answer (score 6):

**iOS 14 update**

It looks that `datePicker.backgroundColor` doesn't work in iOS 14. It works. But you have to put it after `preferredDatePickerStyle` setting:

```
let picker = UIDatePicker()
if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
    picker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
}
picker.backgroundColor = .red
```

Answer (score 5):

```
datePickerName.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

Answer (score 3):

**OBJECTIVE C**

```
datePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]
```

**SWIFT**

```
DatePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
DatePicker.setValue(UIColor.greenColor(), forKeyPath: "textColor")
DatePicker.setValue(0.8, forKeyPath: "alpha")
```

Answer (score 2):

**iOS 14 update**

After iOS 14 setting background color this way

```
datePicker.backgroundColor = <# your bg color #>
```

doesn't work anymore.

So I'm using key value coding approach now:

```
datePicker.setValue(<# your bg color #> , forKey: "backgroundColor")
```

Comment: `datePicker.backgroundColor` works in iOS 14. But you have to put it after `picker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. I just created a UIView and put it behind the UIDatePicker

```
    datePickerBackground = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myDatePickerView.frame];
    datePickerBackground.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view insertSubview:datePickerBackground belowSubview:myDatePickerView];
```

I declared UIView *datePickerBackground; in my class. I reuse this same ViewController so I set datePickerBackground to nil on unLoad.

Answer (score 1):

Simple follow these steps

- First you set the **delegate** in your .**h** file like:

  **UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource**
- Then **add that line** where you created the **datepicker**

  YourDatePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
  YourDatePicker.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
- In your case the color is white but you can change it to as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I would say that [UIDatePicker inherits from UIView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html) and that you could set the background programatically via a line like [`yourDatePickerRef.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/backgroundColor), but it turns out that -- [according to this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469149/uidate-picker-background-color?lq=1) -- UIDatePicker has a number of subviews *inside* of it, some of which are the backgrounds views.

It's these subviews that you need to set the background color to white (instead of clear or whatever it's currently set to).

Yes, it's a bit of a pain, but this makes UIDatePicker a potentially *powerful* object in terms of being able to customize the appearance of.

Comment: Thanks!! I just went through all the layers of this subview. I needed to change object index - 4, 10, and 16 for the right color. I hope Apple will not change the order...:P

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a plain `UIView` behind the picker. Set the view's background color to white. Give the view the same frame as the picker.

**Note** (based on your comment to Michael's answer):

Digging around the private subviews of a `UIDatePicker` is risky. It could break at any time. It is almost guaranteed that your solution will break for date pickers used on a device with a locale that doesn't use AM/PM since the picker will only have two components instead of three.